# How to save multiple user inputs into new variables

Tags: javascript

Im creating a guessing game and the user has 5 attempts to make the correct guess. I want to save their previous guesses (inputs) to show it to them. I have been using the snippet below to save one attempt when the user types into an `<input>` field, but how can I save the next 4 attempts in new variables such as userGuess2, userGuess3, etc.

```
var userGuess = document.getElementById("inputField").value;
$('#previousGuesses').text(userGuess);
```

Comment: Perhaps a list or dictionary where you can store a user and their attempts. Some sort of array or other data structure capable of holding those multiple pieces of information.

Comment: and how do you save that input into your first variable? I don't see an onclick, onchange event to capture their input at the moment

Comment: @ChrisG I have a function and it runs when the user hits enter with their input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok then let's pretend this is your input

```
<input type="text" id="inputField">
```

You can create an index that will increment everytime the users presses enter to save another answer

```
var i=1;
```

And the id name your autogenerated spans will have

```
var name = "previousGuesses";
```

Now on your function you will save the value when the user presses enter like you described and when that happens it will create a new span element where it will display the value stored

```
 function myFunction(){
    $("#inputField").keypress(function( event ) {
        if ( event.which == 13  || event.which == 9) {
            var userGuess = document.getElementById("inputField").value;//get value of the answer
            var span = document.createElement('SPAN');//create a new span
            span.innerHTML = userGuess + "<br>";//answer value goes here
            span.id = name+i;//this is the id of your new span, remember ids are unique so we attach var i to the name var we declared before
            document.body.appendChild(span);
            //$('#previousGuesses'+i).text(userGuess);
        i++;
        }
    });
}
```

now call your function

```
myFunction();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kenpy/m16bojhg/4/

Comment: thanks for the help. Is there any way to have the spans auto generate dynamically when an input is detected rather than having them already exist in the first place? For example, If the user has only guessed once, only have one span. Then after the second guess, a second one auto generates.

Comment: @bikeyredcycle2190 yes let me update my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can just simply add an element for the user's last attempts and add to it.

```
f(guessCount === 1) {
  guesses.textContent = 'Previous guesses: ';
}
guesses.textContent += userGuess + ' ';
```

```js
 var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
      var guesses = document.querySelector('.guesses');
      var lastResult = document.querySelector('.lastResult');
      var lowOrHi = document.querySelector('.lowOrHi');
      var guessSubmit = document.querySelector('.guessSubmit');
      var guessField = document.querySelector('.guessField');
      var guessCount = 1;
      var resetButton;
      guessField.focus();
      function checkGuess() {
        var userGuess = Number(guessField.value);
        if(guessCount === 1) {
          guesses.textContent = 'Previous guesses: ';
        }
        guesses.textContent += userGuess + ' ';
        if(userGuess === randomNumber) {
          lastResult.textContent = "Good job! You win!";
          lastResult.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
          lowOrHi.textContent = '';
          setGameOver();
        } else if(guessCount === 10) {
          lastResult.textContent = 'Hahaha You suck!';
          lowOrHi.textContent = '';
          setGameOver();
        } else {
          lastResult.textContent = "Oops! You're Wrong!";
          lastResult.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
          if(userGuess < randomNumber) {
            lowOrHi.textContent = 'Last guess was too low!';
          } else if(userGuess > randomNumber) {
            lowOrHi.textContent = 'Last guess was too high!';
          }
        }
        guessCount++;
        guessField.value = '';
        guessField.focus();
      }
      guessSubmit.addEventListener('click', checkGuess);
      console.log('cheat is: ' + randomNumber);
      function setGameOver() {
        guessField.disabled = true;
        guessSubmit.disabled = true;
        resetButton = document.createElement('button');
        resetButton.textContent = 'Play Again?';
        document.body.appendChild(resetButton);
        resetButton.addEventListener('click', resetGame);
      }
      function resetGame() {
        guessCount = 1;
        var resetParas = document.querySelectorAll('.resultParas p');
        for(var i = 0 ; i < resetParas.length ; i++) {
          resetParas[i].textContent = '';
        }
        resetButton.parentNode.removeChild(resetButton);
        guessField.disabled = false;
        guessSubmit.disabled = false;
        guessField.value = '';
        guessField.focus();
        lastResult.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
        randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
      }
```

```css
body{
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left top, #c6fced, #a3efda, #7fe3c7, #54d5b3, #00c89f);
  color: #2F3139;
  margin: 10rem auto;
  height:50vh;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.lastResult {
   color: white;
   padding: 3px;
}
button {
  margin-left:3rem ;
}
```

```html
<h3 class="display-4 text-center text-muted text-capitalize"></h3>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 ">
       <h1 class="text-muted text-capitalize">
        <span class="text-primary">JavaScript</span> Number guessing game</h1>

    <p class="lead">Simply enter a number between 1 - 100 then click the button</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="mt-4 d-inline-block">
<div class="form">
      <label for="guessField">Guess a number : </label><input type="text" id="guessField" class="guessField">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit guess" class="guessSubmit">
    </div>

    <div class="resultParas text-center lead">
      <p class="guesses"></p>
      <p class="lastResult"></p>
      <p class="lowOrHi"></p>
    </div>
      </div>
    </div>  </div>
</div>
```

Resource

[JavaScript number guessing game](https://codepen.io/deejay/pen/VdZKpJ)